# WebRTC three-ways communication is creating this error: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I have been trying to create three-ways communication similar to this:

User1 sends an invitation to user2 and user3

User2 receives the invitation from user1 and answers. At the same time, User2 creates another invitation, and sends it to user3

user3 answers both User1 and User2 offers .

To achieve this, I duplicated RTCPeerConnection twice. However, the connection between user 1 and 2 is established correctly, but user 3 is unable to join the call. I'm keep getting this error.

```
Error InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
```

This is my code:

```js
"use strict";

// Get our hostname

var myHostname = window.location.hostname;
console.log("Hostname: " + myHostname);

// WebSocket chat/signaling channel variables.

var connection = null;
var clientID = 0;


var mediaConstraints = {
  audio: false,            // We want an audio track
  video: true             // ...and we want a video track
};

var myUsername = null;
var targetUsername = null;      // To store username of other peer
var targetUsername2 = 'User3'; 
var myPeerConnection = null;    // RTCPeerConnection
var myPeerConnection2 = null;    // RTCPeerConnection


// To work both with and without addTrack() we need to note
// if it's available

var hasAddTrack = false;
var hasAddTrack2 = false;



function log_error(text) {
  var time = new Date();

  console.error("[" + time.toLocaleTimeString() + "] " + text);
}

// Send a JavaScript object by converting it to JSON and sending
// it as a message on the WebSocket connection.

function sendToServer(msg) {
  var msgJSON = JSON.stringify(msg);

  console.log("Sending '" + msg.type + "' message: " + msgJSON);
  connection.send(msgJSON);
}

function setUsername() {
  myUsername = document.getElementById("name").value;

  sendToServer({
    name: myUsername,
    date: Date.now(),
    id: clientID,
    type: "username"
  });
}

// Open and configure the connection to the WebSocket server.

function connect() {
  var serverUrl;
  var scheme = "ws";


  if (document.location.protocol === "https:") {
    scheme += "s";
  }
  serverUrl = scheme + "://" + myHostname + ":443";

  connection = new WebSocket(serverUrl, "json");

  connection.onopen = function(evt) {

  };

  connection.onerror = function(evt) {
    console.dir(evt);
  }

  connection.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var text = "";
    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    console.log("Message received: ");
    console.dir(msg);
    var time = new Date(msg.date);
    var timeStr = time.toLocaleTimeString();

    switch(msg.type) {
      case "id":
        clientID = msg.id;
        setUsername();
        break;

      case "rejectusername":
        myUsername = msg.name;
        break;

      case "userlist":      // Received an updated user list
        handleUserlistMsg(msg);
        break;

      // Signaling messages: these messages are used to trade WebRTC
      // signaling information during negotiations leading up to a video
      // call.

      case "video-offer":  // Invitation and offer to chat
        handleVideoOfferMsg(msg);
        handleVideoOfferMsg2(msg);
        break;

      case "video-answer":  // Callee has answered our offer
        handleVideoAnswerMsg(msg);
        handleVideoAnswerMsg2(msg);
        break;

      case "new-ice-candidate": // A new ICE candidate has been received
        handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg);
        handleNewICECandidateMsg2(msg);
        break;

      case "hang-up": // The other peer has hung up the call
        handleHangUpMsg(msg);
        break;

      // Unknown message; output to console for debugging.

      default:
        log_error("Unknown message received:");
        log_error(msg);
    }
  };
}



function createPeerConnection() {
  console.log("Setting up a connection (myPeerConnection)");

  // Create an RTCPeerConnection which knows to use our chosen
  // STUN server.

  myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [     // Information about ICE servers - Use your own!
      {
        url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
      },
      {
        url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        credential: 'muazkh',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com'
      }
    ]
  });


  // Do we have addTrack()? If not, we will use streams instead.

  hasAddTrack = (myPeerConnection.addTrack !== undefined);

  // Set up event handlers for the ICE negotiation process.

  myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
  myPeerConnection.onremovestream = handleRemoveStreamEvent;
  myPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent;
  myPeerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = handleICEGatheringStateChangeEvent;
  myPeerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = handleSignalingStateChangeEvent;
  myPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = handleNegotiationNeededEvent;

  // Because the deprecation of addStream() and the addstream event is recent,
  // we need to use those if addTrack() and track aren't available.

  if (hasAddTrack) {
    myPeerConnection.ontrack = handleTrackEvent;
  } else {
    myPeerConnection.onaddstream = handleAddStreamEvent;
  }
}






//Clone
function createPeerConnection2() {
  console.log("Setting up a connection... (myPeerConnection2)");

  // Create an RTCPeerConnection which knows to use our chosen
  // STUN server.
  myPeerConnection2 = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [     // Information about ICE servers - Use your own!
      {
        url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
      },
      {
        url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        credential: 'muazkh',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com'
      }
    ]
  });

  // Do we have addTrack()? If not, we will use streams instead.

  hasAddTrack2 = (myPeerConnection2.addTrack !== undefined);

  // Set up event handlers for the ICE negotiation process.
  myPeerConnection2.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent2;
  myPeerConnection2.onremovestream = handleRemoveStreamEvent2;
  myPeerConnection2.oniceconnectionstatechange = handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent2;
  myPeerConnection2.onicegatheringstatechange = handleICEGatheringStateChangeEvent2;
  myPeerConnection2.onsignalingstatechange = handleSignalingStateChangeEvent2;
  myPeerConnection2.onnegotiationneeded = handleNegotiationNeededEvent2;

  // Because the deprecation of addStream() and the addstream event is recent,
  // we need to use those if addTrack() and track aren't available.

  if (hasAddTrack2) {
    myPeerConnection2.ontrack = handleTrackEvent2;
  } else {
    myPeerConnection2.onaddstream = handleAddStreamEvent2;
  }
}


function handleNegotiationNeededEvent() {
  console.log("*** Negotiation needed");

  console.log("---> Creating offer For myPeerConnection1");
  myPeerConnection.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
    console.log("---> Creating new description object to send to remote peer (myPeerConnection)");
    return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("---> Sending offer to remote peer (myPeerConnection1)");
    sendToServer({
      name: myUsername,
      target: targetUsername,
      type: "video-offer",
      sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription
    });
  })
  .catch(reportError);
}



//Clone
function handleNegotiationNeededEvent2() {
  console.log("*** Negotiation needed");
 console.log("---> Creating offer For myPeerConnection2");
 myPeerConnection2.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
   console.log("---> Creating new description object to send to remote peer (myPeerConnection2)");
   return myPeerConnection2.setLocalDescription(offer);
 })
 .then(function() {
   console.log("---> Sending offer to remote peer (myPeerConnection2)");
   sendToServer({
     name: myUsername,
     target: targetUsername2,
     type: "video-offer",
     sdp: myPeerConnection2.localDescription
   });
 })
 .catch(reportError);
}


function handleTrackEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** Track event");
  document.getElementById("received_video").srcObject = event.streams[0];
  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}

function handleTrackEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** Track event");
  document.getElementById("received_video2").srcObject = event.streams[0];
  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}
// Called by the WebRTC layer when a stream starts arriving from the
// remote peer. We use this to update our user interface, in this
// example.

function handleAddStreamEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** Stream added");
  document.getElementById("received_video").srcObject = event.stream;
  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}

function handleAddStreamEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** Stream added");
  document.getElementById("received_video2").srcObject = event.stream;
  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}



function handleRemoveStreamEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** Stream removed");
  closeVideoCall();
}

//Clone
function handleRemoveStreamEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** Stream removed");
  closeVideoCall();
}



function handleICECandidateEvent(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log("Outgoing ICE candidate: " + event.candidate.candidate);

    sendToServer({
      type: "new-ice-candidate",
      target: targetUsername,
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
}


//Clone
function handleICECandidateEvent2(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log("handleICECandidateEvent2")
    console.log("Outgoing ICE candidate: " + event.candidate.candidate);
    sendToServer({
      type: "new-ice-candidate",
      target: targetUsername2,
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
}



function handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** ICE connection state changed to " + myPeerConnection.iceConnectionState);

  switch(myPeerConnection.iceConnectionState) {
    case "closed":
    case "failed":
    case "disconnected":
      closeVideoCall();
      break;
  }

}



//Clone
function handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** ICE connection state changed to " + myPeerConnection2.iceConnectionState);
  switch(myPeerConnection2.iceConnectionState) {
    case "closed":
    case "failed":
    case "disconnected":
      closeVideoCall();
      break;
  }
}



function handleSignalingStateChangeEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: " + myPeerConnection.signalingState);
  switch(myPeerConnection.signalingState) {
    case "closed":
      closeVideoCall();
      break;
  }
}


//Clone
function handleSignalingStateChangeEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** WebRTC signaling state changed to: " + myPeerConnection2.signalingState);
  switch(myPeerConnection2.signalingState) {
    case "closed":
      closeVideoCall();
      break;
  }
}


function handleICEGatheringStateChangeEvent(event) {
  console.log("*** ICE gathering state changed to: " + myPeerConnection.iceGatheringState);
}



function handleICEGatheringStateChangeEvent2(event) {
  console.log("*** ICE gathering state changed to: " + myPeerConnection2.iceGatheringState);
}
// Given a message containing a list of usernames, this function
// populates the user list box with those names, making each item
// clickable to allow starting a video call.

function handleUserlistMsg(msg) {
  var i;

  var listElem = document.getElementById("userlistbox");



  while (listElem.firstChild) {
    listElem.removeChild(listElem.firstChild);
  }

  // Add member names from the received list

  for (i=0; i < msg.users.length; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg.users[i]));
    item.addEventListener("click", invite, false);

    listElem.appendChild(item);
  }
}



function closeVideoCall() {
  var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("received_video");
  var remoteVideo2 = document.getElementById("received_video2");
  var localVideo = document.getElementById("local_video");

  console.log("Closing the call");

  // Close the RTCPeerConnection

  if (myPeerConnection) {
    console.log("--> Closing the peer connection");

    // Disconnect all our event listeners; we don't want stray events
    // to interfere with the hangup while it's ongoing.

    myPeerConnection.onaddstream = null;  // For older implementations
    myPeerConnection.ontrack = null;      // For newer ones
    myPeerConnection.onremovestream = null;
    myPeerConnection.onnicecandidate = null;
    myPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onnotificationneeded = null;

    // Stop the videos

    if (remoteVideo.srcObject) {
      remoteVideo.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    if (localVideo.srcObject) {
      localVideo.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    remoteVideo.src = null;
    localVideo.src = null;

    // Close the peer connection

    myPeerConnection.close();
    myPeerConnection = null;
  }



  //Clone
  if (myPeerConnection2) {
    console.log("--> Closing the peer connection (myPeerConnection2)");

    // Disconnect all our event listeners; we don't want stray events
    // to interfere with the hangup while it's ongoing.

    myPeerConnection2.onaddstream = null;  // For older implementations
    myPeerConnection2.ontrack = null;      // For newer ones
    myPeerConnection2.onremovestream = null;
    myPeerConnection2.onnicecandidate = null;
    myPeerConnection2.oniceconnectionstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection2.onsignalingstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection2.onicegatheringstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection2.onnotificationneeded = null;

    // Stop the videos

    if (remoteVideo2.srcObject) {
      remoteVideo2.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    if (localVideo.srcObject) {
      localVideo.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    remoteVideo2.src = null;
    localVideo.src = null;

    // Close the peer connection

    myPeerConnection2.close();
    myPeerConnection2 = null;
  }

  // Disable the hangup button

  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = true;

  targetUsername = null;
}

// Handle the "hang-up" message, which is sent if the other peer
// has hung up the call or otherwise disconnected.

function handleHangUpMsg(msg) {
  console.log("*** Received hang up notification from other peer");

  closeVideoCall();
}

// Hang up the call by closing our end of the connection, then
// sending a "hang-up" message to the other peer (keep in mind that
// the signaling is done on a different connection). This notifies
// the other peer that the connection should be terminated and the UI
// returned to the "no call in progress" state.

function hangUpCall() {
  closeVideoCall();
  sendToServer({
    name: myUsername,
    target: targetUsername,
    type: "hang-up"
  });

  //Clone
  closeVideoCall();
  sendToServer({
    name: myUsername,
    target: targetUsername2,
    type: "hang-up"
  });
}

// Handle a click on an item in the user list by inviting the clicked
// user to video chat. Note that we don't actually send a message to
// the callee here -- calling RTCPeerConnection.addStream() issues
// a |notificationneeded| event, so we'll let our handler for that
// make the offer.

function invite(evt) {
  console.log("Starting to prepare an invitation");
  if (myPeerConnection) {
    alert("You can't start a call because you already have one open!");
  } else {
    var clickedUsername = evt.target.textContent;

    // Don't allow users to call themselves, because weird.

    if (clickedUsername === myUsername) {
      alert("I'm afraid I can't let you talk to yourself. That would be weird.");
      return;
    }

    // Record the username being called for future reference

    targetUsername = clickedUsername;
    console.log("Inviting user " + targetUsername);

    // Call createPeerConnection() to create the RTCPeerConnection.

    console.log("Setting up connection to invite user: " + targetUsername );
    createPeerConnection();
    console.log("Setting up connection to invite user: " + targetUsername2);
    createPeerConnection2();

    // Now configure and create the local stream, attach it to the
    // "preview" box (id "local_video"), and add it to the
    // RTCPeerConnection.

    console.log("Requesting webcam access...");

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then(function(localStream) {
      console.log("-- Local video stream obtained");
      document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = localStream;

      if (hasAddTrack) {
        console.log("-- Adding tracks to the RTCPeerConnection");
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
      } else {
        console.log("-- Adding stream to the RTCPeerConnection");
        myPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
      }

      if (hasAddTrack2) {
        console.log("-- Adding tracks to the RTCPeerConnection2");
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => myPeerConnection2.addTrack(track, localStream));
      } else {
        console.log("-- Adding stream to the RTCPeerConnection2");
        myPeerConnection2.addStream(localStream);
      }
    })
    .catch(handleGetUserMediaError);
  }
}

// Accept an offer to video chat. We configure our local settings,
// create our RTCPeerConnection, get and attach our local camera
// stream, then create and send an answer to the caller.

function handleVideoOfferMsg(msg) {
  var localStream = null;
  targetUsername = msg.name;

  // Call createPeerConnection() to create the RTCPeerConnection.
  console.log("Starting to accept invitation from " + targetUsername);
  createPeerConnection();

  // We need to set the remote description to the received SDP offer
  // so that our local WebRTC layer knows how to talk to the caller.

  var desc = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp);
  myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(function () {
    console.log("Setting up the local media stream (myPeerConnection1)");
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    console.log("-- Local video stream obtained");
    localStream = stream;
    document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = localStream;

    if (hasAddTrack) {
      console.log("-- Adding tracks to the RTCPeerConnection");
      localStream.getTracks().forEach(track =>
            myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream)
      );
    } else {
      console.log("-- Adding stream to the RTCPeerConnection");
      myPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
    }
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("------> Creating answer");
    // Now that we've successfully set the remote description, we need to
    // start our stream up locally then create an SDP answer. This SDP
    // data describes the local end of our call, including the codec
    // information, options agreed upon, and so forth.
    return myPeerConnection.createAnswer();
  })
  .then(function(answer) {
    console.log("------> Setting local description after creating answer");
    // We now have our answer, so establish that as the local description.
    // This actually configures our end of the call to match the settings
    // specified in the SDP.
    return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
  })
  .then(function() {
    var msg = {
      name: myUsername,
      target: targetUsername,
      type: "video-answer",
      sdp: myPeerConnection.localDescription
    };

    // We've configured our end of the call now. Time to send our
    // answer back to the caller so they know that we want to talk
    // and how to talk to us.

    console.log("Sending answer packet back to other peer");
    sendToServer(msg);
  })
  .catch(handleGetUserMediaError);
}






//Clone
function handleVideoOfferMsg2(msg) {
  var localStream = null;
  // Call createPeerConnection() to create the RTCPeerConnection.

  console.log("Starting to accept invitation from " + targetUsername2);
  createPeerConnection2();

  // We need to set the remote description to the received SDP offer
  // so that our local WebRTC layer knows how to talk to the caller.

  var desc2 = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp);
  myPeerConnection2.setRemoteDescription(desc2).then(function () {
    console.log("Setting up the local media stream... (myPeerConnection2)");
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    console.log("-- Local video stream obtained");
    localStream = stream;
    document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = localStream;

    if (hasAddTrack2) {
      console.log("-- Adding tracks to the RTCPeerConnection (myPeerConnection2)");
      localStream.getTracks().forEach(track =>
            myPeerConnection2.addTrack(track, localStream)
      );
    } else {
      console.log("-- Adding stream to the RTCPeerConnection (myPeerConnection2)");
      myPeerConnection2.addStream(localStream);
    }
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("------> Creating answer (myPeerConnection2)");
    // Now that we've successfully set the remote description, we need to
    // start our stream up locally then create an SDP answer. This SDP
    // data describes the local end of our call, including the codec
    // information, options agreed upon, and so forth.
    return myPeerConnection2.createAnswer();
  })
  .then(function(answer) {
    console.log("------> Setting local description after creating answer (myPeerConnection2)");
    // We now have our answer, so establish that as the local description.
    // This actually configures our end of the call to match the settings
    // specified in the SDP.
    return myPeerConnection2.setLocalDescription(answer);
  })
  .then(function() {
    var msg = {
      name: myUsername,
      target: targetUsername2,
      type: "video-answer",
      sdp: myPeerConnection2.localDescription
    };

    // We've configured our end of the call now. Time to send our
    // answer back to the caller so they know that we want to talk
    // and how to talk to us.

    console.log("Sending answer packet back to other peer (myPeerConnection2)");
    sendToServer(msg);
  })
  .catch(handleGetUserMediaError);
}
// Responds to the "video-answer" message sent to the caller
// once the callee has decided to accept our request to talk.

function handleVideoAnswerMsg(msg) {
  console.log("Call recipient has accepted our call");

  // Configure the remote description, which is the SDP payload
  // in our "video-answer" message.

  var desc = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp);
  myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(desc)
  .catch(reportError);
}

function handleVideoAnswerMsg2(msg) {
  console.log("Call recipient has accepted our call");

  // Configure the remote description, which is the SDP payload
  // in our "video-answer" message.
  var desc2 = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp);
  myPeerConnection2.setRemoteDescription(desc2)
  .catch(reportError);
}

// A new ICE candidate has been received from the other peer. Call
// RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate() to send it along to the
// local ICE framework.

function handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg) {
  var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);
  console.log("Adding received ICE candidate: " + JSON.stringify(candidate));
  myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate)
}


function handleNewICECandidateMsg2(msg) {
  var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);
  console.log("Adding received ICE candidate: " + JSON.stringify(candidate));
  myPeerConnection2.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(reportError);
}

// Handle errors which occur when trying to access the local media
// hardware; that is, exceptions thrown by getUserMedia(). The two most
// likely scenarios are that the user has no camera and/or microphone
// or that they declined to share their equipment when prompted. If
// they simply opted not to share their media, that's not really an
// error, so we won't present a message in that situation.

function handleGetUserMediaError(e) {
  console.log(e);
  switch(e.name) {
    case "NotFoundError":
      alert("Unable to open your call because no camera and/or microphone" +
            "were found.");
      break;
    case "SecurityError":
    case "PermissionDeniedError":
      // Do nothing; this is the same as the user canceling the call.
      break;
    default:
      alert("Error opening your camera and/or microphone: " + e.message);
      break;
  }

  // Make sure we shut down our end of the RTCPeerConnection so we're
  // ready to try again.

  closeVideoCall();
}

// Handles reporting errors. Currently, we just dump stuff to console but
// in a real-world application, an appropriate (and user-friendly)
// error message should be displayed.

function reportError(errMessage) {
  log_error("Error " + errMessage.name + ": " + errMessage.message);
}
```

You can find here the log [file](https://justpaste.it/7kiiq)

Answer (score 1):

You need to better organize your code and everything will work better. Work with , Object, constructoror object creator, send an id of peer to find the correct peer.
Your error message seems to come from the code with the msg switch statement when you call `handleVideoAnswerMsg` , you set the sdp on the 2 peersonnection so on second time the first throw and the second is never called.
You could add an id to choose the correct one
ex:

```
const id = msg.id;
case "video-offer":  // Invitation and offer to chat
        handleVideoOffer(id, msg.sdp);
        break;

      case "video-answer":  // Callee has answered our offer
        handleVideoAnswer(id, msg.sdp);;
        break;

      case "new-ice-candidate": // A new ICE candidate has been received
        handleNewICECandidate(id, msg.ice);
```

You also call createPeerConnection(1/2) on each case